# spring boot rest and angular2 with websocket (stomp over sockjs)

Tags: spring, tomcat, angular, stomp, sockjs

Is it possible to use stomp over sockjs without MVC. So I would like to have spring rest interface in tomcat, and angular2 application run by express.

**WebSocketConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        // the endpoint for websocket connections
        registry.addEndpoint("/portfolio").setAllowedOrigins("*").withSockJS();
    }

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
        config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
    }
}
```

**SocketController.java**

```
@Controller
public class SocketController {

    @Autowired
    private SimpMessagingTemplate template;

    public SocketController() {
        int a = 5;
    }

    @MessageMapping("/greeting")
    public String handle(String greeting) {
        return "[" + "greeting" + ": " + greeting;
    }
}
```

and typescript code:

.
.
.

```
constructor() {

        var socket = new SockJS('http://localhost:8080/portfolio');
        this.stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);
        this.stompClient.connect("guest", "guest", function(frame) {
            console.log('Connected: ' + frame);
            this.stompClient.subscribe('http://localhost:8080/topic/greeting', function(greeting) {
                console.log("from from", greeting);
            });
        }, function (err) {
            console.log('err', err);
        });
    }
```

.
.
.

```
send() {
    this.stompClient.send("http://localhost:8080/app/greeting", {}, JSON.stringify({ 'name': "kitica" }));
}
```

.
.
.

but for some reason this is not working.. in console I get output:

```
Opening Web Socket...
stomp.js:134 Web Socket Opened...
stomp.js:134 >>> CONNECT
login:guest
passcode:guest
accept-version:1.1,1.0
heart-beat:10000,10000



stomp.js:134 <<< CONNECTED
version:1.1
heart-beat:0,0



stomp.js:134 connected to server undefined
activity-socket.ts:17 Connected: CONNECTED
heart-beat:0,0
version:1.1
```

and when I send I get

```
>>> SEND
destination:http://localhost:8080/app/greeting
content-length:17
```

{"name":"kitica"}

but message never comes back to subscriber.

angular2 is on port 8001 and spring rest is on 8080

Comment: If you can use it in JS you can use it in Angular2.

Comment: I have updated question with code sample I have tried, this is according to their documentation

Comment: How did you add sockJS iun your angular2 app please ?

Comment: If your question was more specific I could give more appropriate answer. But it was very simple npm install, and later in your typescript file you have to declare variables SockJS and Stomp. I hope it was helpful. edit: refer to http://stackoverflow.com/a/37094682/2662587

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The part that was confusing is that I am using spring-boot-rest and I am not serving angular2 as static from tomcat container, I have angular2 under webpack so I was constantly trying to subscribe and send to relative URL.

The right way to do is:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {ActivityService} from '../common/services';
import {MaterializeDirective} from 'angular2-materialize';
import {LarsActionButtonComponent} from '../common/components';

var SockJS = require('sockjs-client');
var Stomp = require('stompjs');

@Component({
selector: 'activity',
providers: [ActivityService],
directives: [MaterializeDirective, LarsActionButtonComponent],
templateUrl: 'app/activity/activity.html'
})

export class Activity {
stompClient: any;

activityId: any;
text: any;
messages: Array<String> = new Array<String>();

constructor() {
}

send() {
    this.stompClient.send('/app/hello/' + this.activityId, {},      JSON.stringify({ 'name': this.text }));
}

connect() {
    var that = this;
    var socket = new SockJS('tst-rest.mypageexample/hello?activityId=' + this.activityId);
    this.stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);
    this.stompClient.connect({}, function (frame) {
        console.log('Connected: ' + frame);
        that.stompClient.subscribe('/topic/greetings/' + that.activityId, function (greeting) {
            that.messages.push(JSON.parse(greeting.body).content);
        });
    }, function (err) {
        console.log('err', err);
    });
}

}
```

and in spring controller:

```
@Controller
public class SocketController {


@MessageMapping("/hello")
@SendTo("/topic/greetings")
public Greeting greeting(HelloMessage message) throws Exception {
    return new Greeting("Hello, " + message.getName() + "!");
}

}
```

Configuration class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/hello").setAllowedOrigins("*").withSockJS();
    }

}
```

Comment: What npm library do you use? Is it sufficient to just "npm install stomp"

Comment: please take a look at my answer above, it is just updated

Comment: how did you map `sockjs-client` in webpack?

Comment: I have only 
"sockjs": "0.3.4",
"stompjs": "2.3.3" in package.json, everything else is presented up.

Comment: @critical how to auto reconnect if I lost connection to a socket?

Answer (score 1):

i had myself some issues to work with an angular2 client using stomp over SockJs versus a Java spring-boot back-end. Here what i did to make it working:

On the angular side:

> this.stompClient.subscribe cannot be find, so bind "this" to "that".

```
constructor() {
    var that = this;
    var socket = new SockJS('http://localhost:8080/portfolio');
    this.stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);
    this.stompClient.connect("guest", "guest", function(frame) {
        console.log('Connected: ' + frame);
        that.stompClient.subscribe('http://localhost:8080/topic/greeting', function(greeting) {
            console.log("from from", greeting);
        });
    }, function (err) {
        console.log('err', err);
    });
}
```

On the Java server side:

> Your Controller need an annotation that said where the vallue is returned like this:

```
@MessageMapping("/greeting")
@SendTo("/topic/greetings")
public String handle(String greeting) {
    return "[" + "greeting" + ": " + greeting;
}
```

According to your message broker.

Hope that's help a bit.

Comment: how to auto reconnect if I lost connection to a socket?

Comment: @Lanou Thank you so much, it fixed my issue!

Answer (score 0):

You have send the 'handle()' method value to the subscriber
either using
simpMessagingTemplate.convertAndSend(, );
e.g.- simpMessagingTemplate.convertAndSend("/topic/chats", message.getMessage());

or 
@SendTo("destination url") above the handler method.
e.g.- @SendTo("/topic/message")